# Connecting to Oracle 12C DB Server (12.2.0) Using SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, connection, client, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed Oracle 12C enterprise edition on Windows server 2016 on domain1.com. I was able to create a user that is able to connect to my pluggable DB named pdborcl locally.

However I cannot connect to the pluggable database when i'm on domain2.com using SQL developer. I'm having the error below:
[IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is "host:port:sid"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikf3.png)

I can ping the windows server 2016 from domain2.com. I edit the tnsname.ora file by adding a new connection with the host IP instead of the local host ( See ora files below before and after editing it)

```html
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.domain1.com)
    )
  )

PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl.domain1.com)
    )
  )
```

After editing the file to connect from domain1.com via sql developer

```html
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.domain1.com)
    )
  )

PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl.domain1.com)
    )
  )
  
  PDBORCLTEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.45.88.200)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl.domain1.com)
    )
  )
```

Comment: What is your SQL Developer connection setup?  The error seems to be pointing at an error in the JDBC URL you specified but you haven't shown that bit of information.

Comment: I copied the tnsname.ora file from the oracle server on domain1 and loaded it on SQL developer on a computer from domain2. 

I double-clicked on the PDBORCLTEST connection which prompted me to enter a username and password. I got the error after clicking on OK.

Comment: This issue was resolved. I had to parse the hostname on the HOST item and make sure the DNS is properly setup on the DNS server.